# ValueError: Unbatching a tensor is only supported for rank >= 1

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working on a sample project of California housing price problem and getting above error while training my model.

Following this article 
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/first_steps_with_tensor_flow.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=firststeps-colab&hl=en#scrollTo=pDIxp6vcU809

Comment: Please be more specific, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I figured it out @Sharky , a problem with my code. Thanks

Comment: I think if you update your question with details and also answer your own question it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the error was caused by passing:

```
my_feature = california_housing_dataframe["total_rooms"]
```

into:

```
ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, targets))
```

The solution is to pass:

```
my_feature = california_housing_dataframe[["total_rooms"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`y_train = train_set.pop("satisfaction")`

`train_input_fn = make_input_fn(train_set, y_train) #make_input_fn is the input function`

`linear_est.train(train_input_fn)  # train`

The error for me was that I wrote y_train = "satisfaction" instead of
y_train = train_set.pop("satisfaction"). The pop function will allow you to remove a specified column and save it to in this case the y_train var. You then use to predict that value in your model later on